# Are these Interface classes being instantiated?

Tags: java

The following bit of code is from a Lynda.com episode on parsing xml with Java.

I have been led to believe that Interfaces are like templates and you can't actually instantiate them, but this code looks to me like it has to be instantiating some of the classes marked as interfaces, otherwise how would it work?

Note that the variables `doc`, `list` and `item` all are from Interfaces, get used and have operations on them, yet they all come from interface classes. I am very confused and hope someone can explain please :) `Document`, `Element` and `NodeList` are all marked as interfaces. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;



public class ReadXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss");

            NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
            System.out.println("There are " + list.getLength() + " items.");

            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                Element item = (Element)list.item(i);
                System.out.println(item.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see, there is no command like

```
 Document doc = new Document()
 //...
```

since this would try to create an instance of an interface which, as you know, cannot be done.

What this code does is creating some references on objects which implement those referenced interfaces.

```
class Demo{

    public static void main(String[] args){

         //assuming we have the classes Car and Bus which implement the Interface
         // Vehicle
         Car mycar = new Car(); //Creates new Instance of Car on the Heap
         Bus mybus = new Bus(); //Creates new Instance of Bus on the Heap


         // Now let's try to access them with our interface.
         // By doing so you lose access to all methods and 
         // attributes of your car/bus which are not described in your
         // Interface! 
         Vehicle myvehicle = new Vehicle(); //This will not work!
         Vehicle myvehicle = mycar; //This is fine

         // Lets assume there is another class called "Bike" which 
         // cannot be instantiated directly (keyword: Singleton) but  
         // implements Vehicle             
         Bike mybike = new Bike(); //This won't work!
         Vehicle mybike = Bike.getInstance(); //This is fine
    }
}
```

For further information about the Singleton pattern read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

**Edit:**
I will add some example code for the class Bike here in order to show why `new Bike()` cannot work.

```
public class Bike implements Vehicle{

    //This is the one and only instance of "Bike" in our whole programm.
    //Whenever you need a Bike, you will have to use this one.
    private static Bike bike = new Bike();

    private Bike(){
        //as you see the constructor is private. Only the Class Bike can instantiate a Bike
        //this is the idea of the Singleton-Pattern. There is one and only one instance of something
        //but this instance can be accessed from (all) other classes.
    }

    public static Bike getInstance(){
        //whoever needs the bike has to call getInstance()
        //We will then pass a reference to the private static bike to whoever needs it, since they cannot 
        //create their own bike via new Bike()
        return bike;
    }

    protected static void drive(){
        System.out.println("Bruuum Bruuuum");
    }

    //Overriding some of the Vehicle-methods here.....

    //whoever holds a reference to our bike can now call this method and of course all the methods
    //provided by our Interface

}
```

As you see `new Bike()` can only be called from the class itself, since its a private Method.
We can create as many references to this only instance of "Bike" as we want, but **all of them will always reference the same object**.
Since Bike implements Vehicle we can also create a reference of the Vehicle-part of the Bike which will cast Bike to Vehicle

```
Vehicle v = Bike.getInstance();
```

but there is no way to get another instance of Bike or an instance of Vehicle.

Comment: I'm with you Tim right up until the bike. What I am getting so far is that there can be a reference of type Interface which points to an object of a type that actually can be instantiated. So even though you cannot create the object you can have a "bucket" (or variable) which references a more specific object that IS implemented. Am I getting there? I am lost on the getInstance - it seems totally counterintuitive?

Comment: Hey tentimes, yes you are getting it right. The bike in my example is limited to only one instance of bike, the user/programmer is not able to create a new bike. The only existing bike lives inside the class Bike. I will add some source code and explanation to my example and maybe it will make things more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the variables you mention are of interface types, they are assigned instances of classes that implement those interfaces.

For example, `builder.parse("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss")` would return an instance of a class that implements the `Document` interface, and therefore it can be assigned to the `doc` variable.

It's not different then creating an instance of a class and assigning it to an interface variable. For example :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

When you use only the interface type, you don't need to know the class that implements the interface.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. They seem to be being assigned as items of type of the interface class the way I am reading it.

Comment: e.g. NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("title"); // creates a NodeList type variable called list. SO we now have an instantiated Nodelist type.

Comment: @tentimes If you write `System.out.println(list.getClass().getName())` you will see that the list variable contains an object of some actual class that implements NodeList. You can't instantiate an interface. You can only instantiate a class that implements that interface.

Comment: @tentimes run this example http://ideone.com/TdG0PD on your machine, and you will see which classes are implementing thise interfaces

Comment: @user902383 I have run that example. What I am wondering is where in the scope of things it "decides" or "knows" what specific class (inherited from the interface) to actually use? Is it in the return type of the method?

Comment: @tentimes The method that returns the instance (for example `builder.parse()`) decides which implementation of the interface to return, or calls an internal method that does the decision. The point is that you don't need to care which implementation of the interface is returned. That's the point of using interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

**DocumentBuilderFactory** is an abstract class (declared with abstract key words and in which some class are abstract. This cannot be instancied. But the **DocumentBuilderFactory** offer the method newInstance with provide an instance of  DocumentBuilderFactory see the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)) .

The DocumentBuilder used the DocumentBuilderFactory  method newDocumentBuilder() to provide a DocumentBuilder.

You cannot create instance of this class but here you can get the instance of this class. 
I don't know if you see the difference.